# Access an iterator in 'for' loop, before the loop

Tags: python, for-loop, oop, conditional-statements

I am trying to access an iterator 'obj' before the 'for' loop like this

```
class MyClass:
    CLASS_CONST1 = 'some_rand_const'

    def __init__(self, type, age):
        self.type = type
        self.age = age

var1 = 5
age = 7

# # I tried to individually add the following lines here, none of them work
# obj = MyClass
# obj = MyClass()

condition = obj.type == MyClass.CLASS_CONST1

if var1 > 10:
    condition = obj.type == MyClass.CLASS_CONST1 and obj.age == age

list_of_objects = [MyClass('rand1', 'rand2'), MyClass('rand1', 'rand2'), MyClass('rand1', 'rand2')]

for obj in list_of_objects:
    if condition:
        # do some stuff
        pass
```

The issue is that it is accessed before it is defined (it gets defined in the for loop). And I dont want introduce the condition lines inside the 'for' loop because the lines would be executed in every iteration, and there is no need for that.

The idea is that all this goes into a function and 'var1' and 'age' are arguments of the function.

Comment: what exactly are You trying to achieve? You want to execute a function each iteration with arguments: `obj.type` and `obj.age`, because then just do that, every iteration do: `func(obj.type, obj.age)`

Comment: Based on 'var1', 'condition' changes inside the 'for' loop. How can I change 'condition' outside the 'for' loop?

Comment: You can do that only before the for loop and once unless You change it inside the for loop, or You may try using threads, otherwise I am still confused what You want.

Answer (score 0):

`obj = MyClass` just assigns the class object (not instance) to another variable. `obj = MyClass()` will throw an error because you haven't provided values for `type` and `age` which are required in `__init__`. Did you try `obj = MyClass(var1, age)` ? You did it later for `list_of_objects`.

Anyway, you've tried to create `condition` as a *variable* that is supposed to apply itself during the iteration. That's not how Python works. It's given a static value when it's evaluated the one time. To have it apply to all objects, have `condition` as a function which either take the object or the two variables `type` and `var` as parameters and then return the result of the check:

```py
var1 = 5
age = 7

def condition(obj):
    # will return the True/False result of the check below
    return obj.type == MyClass.CLASS_CONST1 and obj.age == age

for obj in list_of_objects:
    if condition(obj):  # call the function with that object
        # do some stuff
        pass
```

From your code, it's unclear what you wanted in `condition`. Maybe it was this?

```py
var1 = 5  # or put these inside `condition` so they are local
age = 7   # to condition and not globals.
          # Or pass them in as parameters and modify `condition` to accept
          # the additional params

def condition(obj):
    result = obj.type == MyClass.CLASS_CONST1
    if result and var1 > 10:
        # don't re-check `obj.type == MyClass.CLASS_CONST1`
        result = obj.age == age
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `condition` as a simple boolean variable, while its value has to depend on the current values of `obj`. You could use a bunch of functions and assign condition to the relevant one, or as you conditions are simple, you could use lambdas:

condition = obj.type == MyClass.CLASS_CONST1

```
if var1 > 10:
    condition = lambda obj: obj.type == MyClass.CLASS_CONST1 and obj.age == age
else:
    condition = lambda obj: obj.type == MyClass.CLASS_CONST1
```

and then use it as a *variable* function:

```
for obj in list_of_objects:
    if condition(obj):
        # do some stuff
        pass
```